# How do I get the window with the answers for the Average to pop up?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CirclesGUI {

private static JFrame mainFrame;
private static JPanel mainPanel, navPanel, inputPanel, buttonPanel;
private static JLabel radLabel, colLabel;
private static JTextField navField, radField, colField;
private static JButton upButton, downButton, addButton, modifyButton, saveButton, averageButton;

private static int count = 0, nav = 0;
private static Circle circles[] = new Circle[20];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    loadCircleData();
    init();
}

private static void init() {
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Circles");
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));

    navPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    downButton = new JButton("<");
    navField = new JTextField(20);
    navField.setEditable(false);
    navField.setText(circles[nav].toString());
    upButton = new JButton(">");

    navPanel.add(downButton);
    navPanel.add(navField);
    navPanel.add(upButton);

    inputPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    radLabel = new JLabel("Radius");
    radField = new JTextField(5);
    colLabel = new JLabel("Color");
    colField = new JTextField(10);
    inputPanel.add(radLabel);
    inputPanel.add(radField);
    inputPanel.add(colLabel);
    inputPanel.add(colField);

    buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    modifyButton = new JButton("Modify");
    saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    averageButton = new JButton("Average");
    saveButton.setEnabled(false);
    buttonPanel.add(addButton);
    buttonPanel.add(modifyButton);
    buttonPanel.add(saveButton);
    buttonPanel.add(averageButton);

    mainPanel.add(navPanel);
    mainPanel.add(inputPanel);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);

    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
    mainFrame.setSize(350, 300);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    upButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (nav >= count - 1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more circles to show!");
                nav = count;
            } else
                navField.setText(circles[++nav].toString());
        }
    });

    downButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (nav <= 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No more circles to show!");
                nav = 0;
            } else
                navField.setText(circles[--nav].toString());
        }
    });

    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (count >= 20)
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Array full! Maximum 20 circles reached.");
            else {
                if (radField.getText().equals("") || colField.getText().equals(""))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter the circle data to add one!");
                else {
                    double radius = Double.parseDouble(radField.getText().trim());
                    String color = colField.getText().trim();
                    Circle circle = new Circle(radius, color);
                    circles[count++] = circle;
                    nav = count - 1;
                    navField.setText(circles[nav].toString());
                    radField.setText("");
                    colField.setText("");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Circle added successfully! Number of circles = " + count + ".");
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    modifyButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            addButton.setEnabled(false);
            modifyButton.setEnabled(false);
            averageButton.setEnabled(false);
            saveButton.setEnabled(true);
            radField.setText(circles[nav].getRadius() + "");
            colField.setText(circles[nav].getColor());
        }
    });

    saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (radField.getText().equals("") || colField.getText().equals(""))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter the circle data to add one!");
            else {
                double rad = Double.parseDouble(radField.getText().trim());
                String col = colField.getText().trim();
                circles[nav].setRadius(rad);
                circles[nav].setColor(col);
                radField.setText("");
                colField.setText("");
                addButton.setEnabled(true);
                modifyButton.setEnabled(true);
                saveButton.setEnabled(false);
                averageButton.setEnabled(true);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Changes to circle at index " + (nav + 1) + " saved successfully.");
                navField.setText(circles[nav].toString());
            }
        }
    });
}

private static void loadCircleData() {
    circles[count++] = new Circle(5, "White");
    circles[count++] = new Circle(7, "Black");
    circles[count++] = new Circle(9, "Gray");
    circles[count++] = new Circle(11, "Blue");
    circles[count++] = new Circle(13, "Red");
}

private static double getAverage() { 
    double res = 0; 
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < count) {
        res += circles[counter].getRadius(); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();
    }
    return res / circles.length;
    
}
```

}

The question is "Create a program with buttons, labels and text fields. This program should hold data for circles. Create an array of circles (a length of 20 should be fine). The user can enter the radius and color of a circle. There should be an add button to add a user-entered circle, a modify button to change the radius and/or color of a circle and an average button to find the average radius of all circles. You also should have a set of buttons to navigate through your array of circles, displaying the current one for the user in your text fields."

Everything works besides the last part where I have to get the answers of the average Radius to pop up. Not sure what to put in the Message Dialog. Please help me. I'm really not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be too complicated.
You would just have to add the action to your average-Button to display the average like this:

```
averageButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    double average = getAverage();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(mainFrame, "Average: " + average);
});
```

But you also need to fix your getAverage()-Method.
Currently you don't have a working exit-condition because you don't increase your count.
The summing up is okay but you cannot divide in the end by the size of the array as it is fixed and not depending on the current contents.
Instead you could use the counter you are increasing while iterating through the array, so like this:

```
private static double getAverage() { 
    double res = 0; 
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter < count) {
        res += circles[counter].getRadius(); 
        counter++;
        
    }
    return res / counter;
    
}
```

You might just consider replacing your circles-Array with something more dynamic like a List, then you don't have to put this size-check anymore and after summing up the radii, you can really determine the average by saying

```
return res / circles.size()
```